# What is the difference between SMF.Net.WebClient.requestBody and SMF.Net.WebClient.requestString?

Tags: httprequest, webclient, smartface.io

In documentation, there is no clear explanation of requestBody and requestString. If you rely on docs, It seems they both do same job.

Answer (score 0):

RequestString and RequestBody reffers the same property for WebClient object.

When you are posting some datas you can change them dynamically by using RequestString or RequestBody properties.

Comment: Why there are 2 different properties do same things?